# Getting a MySQL Syntax Error after form submission claiming syntax that isn't there

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

When I submit my form, I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 98

However, there is no ')' on line 98. Can anyone help me understand what it is saying is wrong? or where the error is?

Here is line 98:

```
$question84 = $_POST[`question84`];
```

Here is the code for the logic file:

```
<?php

// This function will run within each post array including multi-dimensional arrays
function ExtendedAddslash(&$params) {
    foreach ($params as & $var) {
    // check if $var is an array. If yes, it will start another ExtendedAddslash() function to loop to each key inside.
    is_array($var) ? ExtendedAddslash($var) : $var = addslashes($var);
    }
    }
    // Initialize ExtendedAddslash() function for every $_POST variable
    ExtendedAddslash($_POST);

$question1 = $_POST[`question1`];
$question2 = $_POST[`question2`];
$question3 = $_POST[`question3`];
$question4 = $_POST[`question4`];
$question5 = $_POST[`question5`];
$question6 = $_POST[`question6`];
$question7 = $_POST[`question7`];
$question8 = $_POST[`question8`];
$question9 = $_POST[`question9`];
$question10 = $_POST[`question10`];
$question11 = $_POST[`question11`];
$question12 = $_POST[`question12`];
$question13 = $_POST[`question13`];
$question14 = $_POST[`question14`];
$question15 = $_POST[`question15`];
$question16 = $_POST[`question16`];
$question17 = $_POST[`question17`];
$question18 = $_POST[`question18`];
$question19 = $_POST[`question19`];
$question20 = $_POST[`question20`];
$question21 = $_POST[`question21`];
$question22 = $_POST[`question22`];
$question23 = $_POST[`question23`];
$question24 = $_POST[`question24`];
$question25 = $_POST[`question25`];
$question26 = $_POST[`question26`];
$question27 = $_POST[`question27`];
$question28 = $_POST[`question28`];
$question29 = $_POST[`question29`];
$question30 = $_POST[`question30`];
$question31 = $_POST[`question31`];
$question32 = $_POST[`question32`];
$question33 = $_POST[`question33`];
$question34 = $_POST[`question34`];
$question35 = $_POST[`question35`];
$question36 = $_POST[`question36`];
$question37 = $_POST[`question37`];
$question38 = $_POST[`question38`];
$question39 = $_POST[`question39`];
$question40 = $_POST[`question40`];
$question41 = $_POST[`question41`];
$question42 = $_POST[`question42`];
$question43 = $_POST[`question43`];
$question44 = $_POST[`question44`];
$question45 = $_POST[`question45`];
$question46 = $_POST[`question46`];
$question47 = $_POST[`question47`];
$question48 = $_POST[`question48`];
$question49 = $_POST[`question49`];
$question50 = $_POST[`question50`];
$question51 = $_POST[`question51`];
$question52 = $_POST[`question52`];
$question53 = $_POST[`question53`];
$question54 = $_POST[`question54`];
$question55 = $_POST[`question55`];
$question56 = $_POST[`question56`];
$question57 = $_POST[`question57`];
$question58 = $_POST[`question58`];
$question59 = $_POST[`question59`];
$question60 = $_POST[`question60`];
$question61 = $_POST[`question61`];
$question62 = $_POST[`question62`];
$question63 = $_POST[`question63`];
$question64 = $_POST[`question64`];
$question65 = $_POST[`question65`];
$question66 = $_POST[`question66`];
$question67 = $_POST[`question67`];
$question68 = $_POST[`question68`];
$question69 = $_POST[`question69`];
$question70 = $_POST[`question70`];
$question71 = $_POST[`question71`];
$question72 = $_POST[`question72`];
$question73 = $_POST[`question73`];
$question74 = $_POST[`question74`];
$question75 = $_POST[`question75`];
$question76 = $_POST[`question76`];
$question77 = $_POST[`question77`];
$question78 = $_POST[`question78`];
$question79 = $_POST[`question79`];
$question80 = $_POST[`question80`];
$question81 = $_POST[`question81`];
$question82 = $_POST[`question82`];
$question83 = $_POST[`question83`];
$question84 = $_POST[`question84`];
$question85 = $_POST[`question85`];
$question86 = $_POST[`question86`];
$question87 = $_POST[`question87`];
$question88 = $_POST[`question88`];
$question89 = $_POST[`question89`];
$question90 = $_POST[`question90`];
$question91 = $_POST[`question91`];
$question92 = $_POST[`question92`];
$question93 = $_POST[`question93`];
$question94 = $_POST[`question94`];
$fname = $_POST[`fname`];
$lname = $_POST[`lname`];
$birthday = $_POST[`birthday`];


// Database Credentials
$db_host ='XXXXXXXXXX';
$db_username ='XXXXXXXXXX';
$db_password ='XXXXXXXXXX';
$db_name ='XXXXXXXXXX';
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);


mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysqli_error($con)); //Connect your MYSQL database
mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name); //Select your corresponding database where your table is located'table_name'


$query = "SELECT * FROM `CSARCS-A` WHERE `question1` = '$question1'";
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `CSARCS-A` (question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9, question10, question11, question12, question13, question14, question15, question16, question17, question18, question19, question20, question21, question22, question23, question24, question25, question26, question27, question28, question29, question30, question31, question32, question33, question34, question35, question36, question37, question38, question39, question40, question41, question42, question43, question44, question45, question46, question47, question48, question49, question50, question51, question52, question53, question54, question55, question56, question57, question58, question59, question60, question61, question62, question63, question64, question65, question66, question67, question68, question69, question70, question71, question72, question73, question74, question75, question76, question77, question78, question79, question80, question81, question82, question83, question84, question85, question86, question87, question88, question89, question90, question91, question92, question93, question94, fname, lname, birthday)
                                VALUES ('$question1',
                                        '$question2',
                                        '$question3',
                                        '$question4',
                                        '$question5',
                                        '$question6',
                                        '$question7',
                                        '$question8',
                                        '$question9',
                                        '$question10',
                                        '$question11',
                                        '$question12',
                                        '$question13',
                                        '$question14',
                                        '$question15',
                                        '$question16',
                                        '$question17',
                                        '$question18',
                                        '$question19',
                                        '$question20',
                                        '$question21',
                                        '$question22',
                                        '$question23',
                                        '$question24',
                                        '$question25',
                                        '$question26',
                                        '$question27',
                                        '$question28',
                                        '$question29',
                                        '$question30',
                                        '$question31',
                                        '$question32',
                                        '$question33',
                                        '$question34',
                                        '$question35',
                                        '$question36',
                                        '$question37',
                                        '$question38',
                                        '$question39',
                                        '$question40',
                                        '$question41',
                                        '$question42',
                                        '$question43',
                                        '$question44',
                                        '$question45',
                                        '$question46',
                                        '$question47',
                                        '$question48',
                                        '$question49',
                                        '$question50',
                                        '$question51',
                                        '$question52',
                                        '$question53',
                                        '$question54',
                                        '$question55',
                                        '$question56',
                                        '$question57',
                                        '$question58',
                                        '$question59',
                                        '$question60',
                                        '$question61',
                                        '$question62',
                                        '$question63',
                                        '$question64',
                                        '$question65',
                                        '$question66',
                                        '$question67',
                                        '$question68',
                                        '$question69',
                                        '$question70',
                                        '$question71',
                                        '$question72',
                                        '$question73',
                                        '$question74',
                                        '$question75',
                                        '$question76',
                                        '$question77',
                                        '$question78',
                                        '$question79',
                                        '$question80',
                                        '$question81',
                                        '$question82',
                                        '$question83',
                                        '$question84',
                                        '$question85',
                                        '$question86',
                                        '$question87',
                                        '$question88',
                                        '$question89',
                                        '$question90',
                                        '$question91',
                                        '$question92',
                                        '$question93',
                                        '$question94',
                                        '$fname',
                                        '$lname',
                                        '$birthday', ) ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

?>
```

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: `$lname',
                                        '$birthday', ) ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

?>`  You can see an extra comma after '$birthday' remove that and check again

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to line 98 of the actual SQL command

I think it's the comma after `'$birthday'`

So replace `'$birthday', ) ")` with `'$birthday' ) ")`